# How to write to Nginx access log from custom module

Tags: c++, nginx, error-log

I'm writing a custom Nginx module (in C++). I am able to add any message to Nginx' error log without any issues, like:

```
std::cerr << "some content";
```

I do not know how to add something to Nginx' access log. I tried functions like `ngx_log_debug0` but without success:

```
ngx_log_debug0(NGX_LOG_INFO, log, 0, "some content");
```

I tried this in two contexts:

1. I have a postconfiguration function with `ngx_conf_t *cf` as a parameter from where I take `log` variable used above (as a second parameter):

   `cf->log`
2. I have a function which handles http requests as a command which has interface:
   `ngx_int_t my_function(ngx_http_request_t *r);` from where also tried to use `log` but also without success:
   `r->connection->log`

Do I need to setup smth? Everything else works fine. Perhaps it is not possible to add custom messages to original access log?

Comment: Define "without success" in specific technical terms.

Comment: "without success" means that 'some content' is not added to the access log.